# how to reflect change in URL without adding reloadOnSearch:false to all routes

Tags: angularjs

I recently added i18n to my site, and I want the selected language to reflect on the URL.

So I added  `$location.search('lang', language);` in my code.

however - now every page I enter refresh. so I started adding  `reloadOnSearch:false` to all routes, but then I got the feeling I am doing something wrong.

What is the proper way to implement this?